# PhantomJs ignores URL after #

Tags: c#, phantomjs

I'm trying to navigate to a URL that looks like that: https://my-website.test.com/web/uk/demo/#/verify?vtoken=35cVc7g5-e842-44e5-8756-5683b8b3fc3c

The problem is, for some reason, PhantomJS navigates to https://my-website.test.com/web/uk/demo/ ignoring all the rest (including the token I need). What could it be? Considering that all the other browsers work just fine. (Chrome, IE and Firefox).

There's no much code, basically is a simple line:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(new Uri(theUrl));
```

Is there a solution for that? I'm using Visual Studio/C# with Specflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Check what `new Uri(theUrl)` is returning. I suspect it is Uri that is removing the part after #

Comment: I've just checked. It keeps all the Url. I also tried passing the the url as string. Same result on PhantomJS

Comment: Not exactly a solution but I found out what was happening. The link I was passing redirects to another one. If I use the redirected URL to navigate on PhantomJS it works!